# I got this error when install npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I got this error.

```
 npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried many sources. But cant resolve the error. As this error, i have tried to install node-gyp. But at that time it is showing another dependency. So is there any way to install the dependencies at a time ?

Comment: Which package does install fail for? Which versions of NodeJS and NPM are you running?

Comment: I just run this code " sudo apt install npm "

Comment: Please run `npm --version` and `node --version`.

Comment: This is what i am getting =====>The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the old version of node and npm you have and try using the following steps to install a newer version using node version manager, after that try to install your package.

```
//Remove node
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs npm

//Remove any leftover files that gives version issues
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules 

//Install nvm, this will install npm 5.4
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash

//To uninstall a node version 
//nvm uninstall <version>

nvm install <version you want>

nvm use <version you installed>

//check with 
node -v
npm -v
```